# Get results where multiple IDs are present in list (contains all)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using EF6 and I have the following

```
public partial class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemID{ get; set; }

    public string ItemName{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item_Tags> Item_Tags { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item_Tags
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemTagID { get; set; }

        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        public int ItemTagPropID { get; set; }

        public virtual Item_TagProps Item_TagProps { get; set; }

        public virtual Items Items { get; set; }

    }
```

And I have a List Tags that has multiple {23,27,44} ItemTagPropID values.

What I need is to find all items that match all ItemTagPropID in List Tags.

I have a following code that gets all the items that have any ItemTagPropID from List Tags

```
ItemList = db.Items.Where(u => u.Item_Tags.Any(l => Tags.Contains(l.ItemTagPropID)));
```

So if item has ItemTagPropID of 23 but does not have 27 it still gets in the list.

How to get only Items that have all members of the list ?

The following code gives no results (replaced Any with All)

```
ItemList = db.Items.Where(u => u.Item_Tags.All(l => Tags.Contains(l.ItemTagPropID)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for all items that have all the tags in Tags.
What you wrote is the opposite: items that all their tags are in Tags.
What you need is:

```
ItemList = db.Items.Where(u => Tags.All(l => u.Item_Tags.Select(item_tag => item_tag.ItemTagPropID).ToList().Contains(l)));
```

Comment: Tags is List<int> so I dont have l.ItemTagPropID

Comment: Error 117 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'W3SR.Entities.Item_Tags'

Comment: I've made 2 edits, I've also added the Select potion, are you testing it with or without it?